# How "this" escapes from a published inner class

Tags: java, escaping, this

I'm reading the book Java Concurrency in Practice. In section 3.2 it talks about escaping outer class while publishing inner classes. Now I'm looking for the syntax that makes it possible. Let's say we have:

```
public class ThisEscape {

    public Integer i = 47;

    public ThisEscape(EventSource source) {
        source.registerListener(
            new EventListener() {
                public void onEvent(Event e) {
                    doSomething(e);
                }
        });
    }
}
```

If I got it right about escaping outer class, I assume that `EventSource` somehow can access `EventListener` enclosing class (in this case `ThisEscape`). Say we implement `EventSource` as the following:

```
public class EventSource {

    public void registerListener(EventListener listener) {
        // How does it have access to enclosing class of the listener variable i?
    }

}
```

Just how can we have access to the public variable `i` from `registerListener`?

---

Just found a typo. Replaced  "`EventSource` enclosing class" with  "`EventListener` enclosing class". Fortunately everybody got the right version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine `EventSource` is written something like this:

```
public class EventSource {
    public void registerListener(EventListener listener) {
        listener.onEvent(null);
    }
}
```

For the purposes of the memory model it doesn't matter that it doesn't have direct access to the `ThisEscape` object. (It might - reflection, some method on `EventListener`, in the same package, enabled by some method in the same package, etc.) What matters is that the fields of `ThisEscape` are being accessed in some manner, which will likely be thread-unsafe.

Comment: Did you mean to actually use a variable from `ThisEscape`?

Comment: @Shakedown reading or writing any (non-static) field of `ThisEscape` should do it. In this case `i` may or may not be visible in another thread, even if it was `final` (although if a non-null value is read, it will be a fully initialised `47` as `Integer` happens to be safe even with unsafe-publication).

Comment: Don't you actually need to read or write a non-static field of `ThisEscape` though? Your code doesn't use `i`.

Comment: @Shakedown My code calls `ThisEscape.doSomething` which presumably does something, which would be on the fields of its instance.

Comment: Huh? I don't see your code doing that, I see `listener.onEvent(null)`.

Comment: @Shakedown ...and `onEvent` calls `doSomething`.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin. Thanks for your response. Reflection api just gives you the names of the fields, methods, or a way to instantiate an enclosing class. And I'm not interested of having access to ThisEscape in _any_ _manner_ but through published inner class in EventSource. Something similar to ThisEscape.this when implementing anonymous inner class EventListener. You can access i from anywhere but then you're accessing ThisEscape directly.

Comment: @SHOJAEIBAGHINI My answer is referring to the same thing as the book. I am not sure what you are trying to get at. (Reflection does allow reading fields from objects.)

Comment: @Tom Hawtin. Add a no-arg constructor to ThisEscape, you can go with Reflection only so far: Field[] fields = listener.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getFields();
  for (int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
   try {
    if(fields[j].getName() == "i") {
     ThisEscape te = (ThisEscape) listener.getClass().getEnclosingClass().newInstance();
     fields[j].set(te, new Integer(43));
    }
   } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
...   }
  }

Comment: @SHOJAEIBAGHINI `public void registerListener(EventListener listener) {
        try {
            Class<? extends EventListener> listenerClass = listener.getClass();
            Field outerThisField = listenerClass.getDeclaredField("this$0");
            Object thisEscape = outerThisField.get(listener);
            Field iField = ThisEscape.class.getDeclaredField("i");
            System.err.println(iField.get(thisEscape));
        } catch (Throwable exc) {
            throw new Error(exc);
        }
    }` (but not really relevant)

Comment: @Tom Hawtin. This is indeed the syntax I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SHOJAEIBAGHINI Note that I am not actually suggesting using that code!

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I was looking at a way that this might be possible not using it, per se. The way you showed, another thread can access i and modify it, which means ThisEscape actually escaped via an inner class.

Answer (score 4):

The `ThisEscape` publishes the `EventListener` via the registration.
But *at the same time* it implicitly publishes the enclosing `ThisEscape` instance since inner class instances contain *a hidden reference to the enclosing class*.
It is explained in the book. Read on.
This example illustrates how `this` can escape *during* construction.
The closest I am able to describe this syntactically is like:

```
public class ThisEscape {

    public Integer i = 47;

    public ThisEscape(EventSource source) {
            source.registerListener(
                    new EventListener() {
                            ThisEscape outerRef = ThisEscape.this;//added by compiler
                            public void onEvent(Event e) {
                                    doSomething(e);
                            }
                    });
            }
    }
```

Perhaps a friend here can give a more exact/accurate technical syntax.
But the compiler adds some extra code so that the inner class can have access to the members of the outer class as you can see.
The problem here is that the object published is under construction i.e. not fully constructed which most definitely is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, when you define an inner class it automatically adds the parent to all of the constructors of the inner class, including the default no-arg constructor, and assigns it to a hidden field.  This is how you can reference the fields of the parent class in the inner class.  You can see this in the bytecode representation of your class:

```
public class test/ThisEscape {

  // compiled from: ThisEscape.java
  // access flags 0x0
  INNERCLASS test/ThisEscape$1 null null

  // access flags 0x1
  public Ljava/lang/Integer; i

  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>(Ltest/EventSource;)V
      L0
    LINENUMBER 8 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 6 L1
    ALOAD 0
    BIPUSH 47
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Integer.valueOf (I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    PUTFIELD test/ThisEscape.i : Ljava/lang/Integer;
   L2
    LINENUMBER 9 L2
    ALOAD 1
    NEW com/kcp/ko/pm/ThisEscape$1
    DUP
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL test/ThisEscape$1.<init> (Lcom/kcp/ko/pm/ThisEscape;)V
    INVOKEVIRTUAL test/EventSource.registerListener (Lcom/kcp/ko/pm/EventListener;)V
   L3
    LINENUMBER 17 L3
    RETURN
   L4
    LOCALVARIABLE this Ltest/ThisEscape; L0 L4 0
    LOCALVARIABLE source Ltest/EventSource; L0 L4 1
    MAXSTACK = 4
    MAXLOCALS = 2
}
```

Notice the public `test/ThisEscape$1.<init> (Ltest/ThisEscape;)V` constructor

This causes a problem (highlighted in the book) when defining inner classes in the constructor of another class.  Essentially you will be "leaking" a reference to a partially initialized class.

You have your escaping situration a bit wrong.  The `this` parameter escapes through the definition of the EventListener anonymous inner class.  To get access to the variable `i` in the exported version of the EventListener class you need to do the following:

```
public class ThisEscape {

    public Integer i = 47;

    public ThisEscape(EventSource source) {
        source.registerListener(new ExportedEventListener(this));
    }
}

public class ExportedEventListener implements EventListener{

    private ThisEscape thisEscape;

    public ExportedEventListener(ThisEscape thisEscape){
        this.thisEscape = thisEscape;
    }

    public void onEvent(Event e) {
        System.out.println("i: " + thisEscape.i);
    }
}
```

But this is still not thread safe.

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129592/reference-of-enclosing-object-escape-through-anonymous-class-java)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my question is not about the problem during construction (which I'm working on now to find the syntax that may break the code). And your example demonstrates another situation. You just published ThisEscape object directly not through a published inner class, which has access to the outer class-as you showed perfectly.

Comment: Ok, rereading your question, are you looking to figure out how you can access i within the registerListener method?

Comment: In your scenario eventSource does not have access to i, and the registerListener() method would likewise not have access.  One way you can get access to i within the regsiterListener method is to add it as a parameter like so: registerListener(EventListener listener, Integer i).

Comment: Well, I need an indirect way to show how ThisEscape escapes via publishing inner class. Ok, maybe there is no such a syntax!